# render to color attachment with DSA

Tags: opengl

I want to render into a framebuffer with DSA. However I only got it working when manually binding the framebuffer. Is there a way without bind it?

This is how I thought it would work:

```
glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer(m_fbo, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0);
drawCall();
```

This only works if I use `glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_fbo);` before. How do I do it correctly?

Also, what is the equivalent to `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` for framebuffers with DSA? Again, I can only clear if I previously bound the framebuffer.

Comment: IIRC DSA is for modifying objects without binding them, but to actually use them, you still have to bind them.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two: Buffers and Textures can be used without binding though. I guess they didn't implement it completely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array of draw buffers is not a global state, but rather it is stored per-framebuffer. You are probably familiar with the mechanics of Vertex Array Objects, which maintain separate sets of vertex attribute pointers; draw buffers are analogous to attribute pointers in this situation.

When you make a call to `glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffer (m_fbo, ...)`, you are modifying the state of `m_fbo`'s array without first having to bind `m_fbo`. You are not actually telling OpenGL to source its color buffer from `m_fbo`'s `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` - that only happens when you bind `m_fbo`.

In fact, if you think about this critically, this is the only logical way it can work. If you could arbitrarily source buffers from different framebuffer objects, then that would violate validation (completeness). For instance, FBO0 might have a multi-sampled color attachment with 4 samples and FBO1 might have a single-sampled depth attachment. Those are two incompatible buffers, but the only time that is validated is when you try to attach those two images to the same FBO.